# Bump function, gluing diffeomorphisms

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, analytic-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $f(x)$ be the bump function 
$$
f(x_1,\dots,x_N)\triangleq \prod_{i=1}^N exp\left(
\frac{1}{1-x_i^2}
\right),
$$ $I$ be the identity matrix and, $R$ be a special orthogonal matrix not equal to $-I$.  Then is
$$
x\mapsto (f(x)R + (1-f(x))I)\cdot x,
$$
a $C^1(\mathbb{R}^N,\mathbb{R}^N)$-diffeomorphism (moreover, is it analytic)?

Comment: I assume you mean to define $f$ piecewise, so that it vanishes outside the cube $|x_i|<1$? This will certainly not be analytic (think about the unique continuation), and I doubt it's a diffeomorphism - just the obvious failure in the case of $R = -I$ is far from special. If you want to interpolate between rotations like this then it's a better idea to do your interpolation inside $SO(n)$ rather than linearly.

Comment: So you're suggesting something like: $x\mapsto exp(f(x)X)\cdot x$ would work?  (Where $X\in so(D)$?)

Comment: Perfect!  That works just like I wanted thanks!  Unless I'm missing something, I'll post the answer and gie you some points too...once I can reward :)

Comment: Yeah, that's essentially what I meant, though it's only obvious that it works if you use an $f$ that is radially symmetric.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks a ton!  I'll write it up shortly:)